# 2004 honda civic low beams not working but high beams work

Tags: honda, civic, headlight

My low beams wont work but every other lights work fine. I changed my light switch column, tested the fuses and relay, still not working. Is there anything more to check besides the wiring?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps the bulbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you actually changed the bulbs before you did anything else. The first step in diagnosing further is to use a multimeter to check whether power is being supplied to the light sockets. Touch the probes to the light contacts and see if you get the right voltage. If you aren't getting the right voltage, which I would expect if your lights aren't working then you need to work your way back from the contacts until you find the problem.

First check the contacts for contamination. Oxidation and general gunk can form a layer that prevents good contact, but the good news is it's easy to clean off. If they are contaminated then contact cleaner and scraping are the way to go, I use a Dremel with a grinder bit to lightly scour the contacts if I can reach them, otherwise a small flat bladed screwdriver often does the trick.

Once you have eliminated the contacts as the source of the problem check the wiring harness next up from the socket, if there's voltage there then the problem is between the harness and the socket. If there isn't voltage then you work back from there.